# Pyinstaller issue with subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

When I have subprocess.check_output function in mycode and I generate an .exe file using pyinstaller with

```
python pyinstaller.py    --noconsole -F myprogram.py
```

process stop to work, otherwise every thing is ok!

Do you know any solution with pyinstaller or replace subprocess library with some thing else?

Comment: if there is no console then make sure that you redirect all stdout/stderr to a file from your script and its children (e.g., that are invoked by `check_output()`). Also check that `stdin` is not used; you could redirect it from `os.devnull` for child processes.

Comment: that's some bug with subprocess or what? but when I use os.popen() instead that works well with pyinstaller

Comment: try to reproduce the error with [`subprocess32` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32).

Comment: there is no error to reproduce that simply stop to work when built using --noconsole and works when no noconsole param used

Comment: you said it works with `os.popen()`. Does it work with `subprocess32`?

Comment: I couldn't try subprocess32 because when i try to install it it says that need some files.bat searching google realized I should use mingw32 to build that but when i try to build using mingw32 it errors occur!

Comment: I forced to get back to subprocess library, how ever forgetting about -F switch solved every thing and my program work in one directory mode.