# PyInstaller + subprocess.check_output + Windows Scheduled task

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, pyinstaller

this is a topic for somebody who may face similar thing in future.
Once you try to schedule task in Windows using executable that was compiled with PyInstaller with option -noconsole and trying to use subprocess.check_output it does not work

Funny thing that if you call .exe directly then it works perfectly fine. However if you schedule a task or try to wrap execution into batch like:

```
C:\git\backend.exe -p C:\Users\settings.json
```

then it fails without any error code.
Only thing one can found is in tasks event log is error code: 2147942401

Answer (score 1):

solution will be to explicitly specify Popen with stdin, out, err

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
p.communicate()
```

I found similar topics but just want to explicitly mention that by default command call or .exe double click it works but not from scheduled task

Inspired from here:
[Pyinstaller issue with subprocess.check_output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613642/pyinstaller-issue-with-subprocess-check-output)
[Pyinstaller subprocess.check_output error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512836/pyinstaller-subprocess-check-output-error)
[pyinstaller on Windows with --noconsole simply won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455337/pyinstaller-on-windows-with-noconsole-simply-wont-work)

PS
I always look for better solutions, if you have one, please suggest!